# How do I know that my site has good search?

Tags: search

I run a lot of internal CMS and LMS systems.  We have a lot of search systems that include everything from in-doc to straight database text to field weighting to tagging.  We cannot use google because often we have sensitive information, behind proxies, or using vendor driven data.

We are constantly trying to update the search on these sites to make things more relevant.  Little tweaks here and there are weekly things.

Most of these tweaks are not apparent to the user while some are in their face.  All are done with the common sense understanding that we are trying to bring up less "old or bad" docs or pages.

From a developer and admin how do I understand if search is working better from a user perspective though other than poll them?  Often in these polls the reflected data is skewed more towards the lack of information than the search itself.  So I am wondering if there are any industry measures I can use to prove search success?

**Note:** So there isn't confusion I do not care about hits - for most sites the site I am programming is their only choice.  I want to know how effective the search is?

(All of our sites are php/mysql on Windows 2008 R2 if that is relevant to anyone)

Comment: put a hit counter on it

Comment: @RachelGallen - we have page stats on everything.  What does hits prove?

Comment: if you have a high hitcount that means people are visiting your page. ideally you should count the number of returning visitors too. flagcounter.com  has a handy hitcounter on it

Comment: why can you not use google analytics or a tracker like that? bing have a similar tool it counts bounce rate and everything

Comment: How is this a programming question? It asks nothing related in any way to programming (code) or programmers tools.

Comment: @RachelGallen - I don't care how many people hit page.  I care how effective the search is.  I want to measure how well the documents/pages coming up.

Comment: @KenWhite - what stack should it be on then?  It is about programming if I need to create some sort of analysis engine based on set criteria.

Comment: @RachelGallen - I am sorry you have no idea what I am asking and you are confusing everything.  Please just delete your comments.